# Opportunity field is missing so quote is not inserting

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, error

I am using following webservice but my quotes are not inserting it showing an error may i know how to modify my code. for insert of quotes. Can anyone give me suggestions how to modify my code for quote insert. while inserting it showing an error opportunity Id filed missing

```
           for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[i].quotes.size();j++)
           {
            qu = new Quote();
            qu.Name = req.accounts[i].quotes[j].qName;
           // op.CloseDate =system.today();
           // op.StageName = req.accounts[i].opps[j].oStage;
            qu.OpportunityId = srList[i].id;
            qList.add(qu); 
           }
            Database.insert(qList);  

        }
       }
         return res;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When inserting quote in sfdc its important and mandatory to associate the Opportunity to the quote .

In your code for opportunity Id for quote i am seeing you are not populating the Id properly ,

```
for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[i].quotes.size();j++){
        qu = new Quote();
        qu.Name = req.accounts[i].quotes[j].qName;
        qu.OpportunityId = oppList[i].id;//important to populate this .In your code i see you have Account Id instead .
        qList.add(qu); 
       }
```

Comment: once you replace with opportunity Id as we have suggested things will work

Comment: The context of question is different .Describe in next question to get proper attention

Comment: i post a new question can you give me suggestions.for product insert i update the code also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your last `for` loop, when you're trying to populate `qu.OpportunityId`. You have

```
qu.OpportunityId = srList[i].id;
```

But `srList` is holding results from when you inserted Accounts, not Opportunities, so you aren't correctly populating the field.